# Salesforce apex csv file generation

Tags: csv, salesforce, apex, apex-code

Hope everyone is safe.
I'm trying to generate a csv file using apex code. From salesforce I just want to take out all payments from payments object that have a status of Paid and then check if Number field's value (from payments object in salesforce) is present in my payment api response. I want to generate csv file only for that records and email it to myself.
**Right now in salesforce sandbox, I'm getting good results when I test csv all such payment records whose status are paid are showing in csv file but**

> when I move to production I get only 1 record in my csv file. Don't
> know why in sandbox it is running fine but in production it's not.

```
public with sharing class EmailCsv {
public static String APIAccessID;
public static String APISecureKey;
public static String orgId;
Public static String locId;
public static String apiBaseUrl;
public static String finalstr;


@InvocableMethod(label=‘Invoke From Flow' description=‘Invokable Method') 
public static void invokeFromFlow() {
    makeCallout();
}


@future(callout=true)
public static void makeCallout() {
    List<String> paymentNo = new List<String>();
    List<Payments__c> paymentQuery= [SELECT Number__c, Status__c FROM Payments__c where Status__c = ‘Paid’];
    for(Payments__c pNo : paymentQuery){
        paymentNo.add(pNo.Number__c);
    }
    string header = 'Order Number,Status,Amount,Received Date,Received Time \n';
    finalstr = header;
    if(Test.isRunningTest()) {
        APIAccessID = '';
        APISecureKey = '';
        orgId = '';
        apiBaseUrl = '';
        locId = '';
    } else {
         APIAccessID = Email_Csv__c.getInstance('APIAccessID').value__c;
        APISecureKey = Email_Csv__c.getInstance('APISecureKey').value__c;
        orgId = Email_Csv__c.getInstance('orgId').value__c;
        apiBaseUrl = Email_Csv__c.getInstance('apiBaseUrl').value__c;
        locId = Email_Csv__c.getInstance('locId').value__c;
        
    }

    String authHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(APIAccessID + ':' + APISecureKey));
    String endpoint = apiBaseUrl + '/organizations/' + orgId + '/locations/' + locId + '/transactions/';
    System.debug('Endpoint is ==> ' +endpoint);
    HTTP http = new HTTP();
    HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest();
    request.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    request.setMethod('GET');
    request.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    request.setHeader('Authorization', authHeader);
    request.setHeader('X-Forte-Auth-Organization-Id', orgId);
    request.setTimeout(5000);
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
    if(response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        EmailCsvWrapper resWrapper = EmailCsvWrapper.parse(response.getBody());
        for(Integer i=0; i<resWrapper.results.size(); i++) {
        EmailCsvWrapper.Results res = resWrapper.results.get(i);
        String s = res.received_date;
        Double authAmount = res.authorization_amount;
        String authAmountConverted = String.valueOf(authAmount);
        String oNumber = res.order_number;
        if(oNumber != null){
        String[] splittedoNumber = oNumber.split(',');
        oNumber = oNumber.contains(',') ? splittedoNumber[0] : oNumber;
        }
            for(String s : paymentNo){
            if(s == oNumber){
                    String cfn = +oNumber + ',' +res.status + ',' +authAmountConverted + ',' +s  + '\n';
                    finalstr = finalstr +cfn;
                    System.debug('CSV => ' +cfn);
            }
            }
    }
        
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage semail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
    blob csvBlob = blob.valueOf(finalstr);
    attach.setFileName(‘Payments.csv');
    attach.setBody(csvBlob);
    List<String> emailAddresses = new List<String>();
    emailAddresses.addAll((Email_Csv__c.getInstance('EmailAddresses').value__c).split(';'));
    semail.setSubject('Csv File’);  
            semail.setToAddresses(emailAddresses);
    semail.setPlainTextBody(‘Transactions csv file’);
    semail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{attach});
    emails.add(semail);
    Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
        
    }
    
    
}
```

}

Comment: `SELECT Number__c, Status__c FROM Payments__c where Status__c = 'Paid'` - well, does this return more than 1 row in production? Running as sysadmin or end user, maybe you have some sharing rule problems. If you send more than 1 record to the API but get only 1 result back - you'll have to contact people that support this API, it won't exactly be a Salesforce question...

Comment: yes it shows 17 rows in production

Comment: I'm not sending records to API. I'm just comparing records in salesforce object (payment object) and then if particular record exists in API Get call (Based on Number which is common in API response and in Salesforce field). If particular record exists, I want to show that in csv file (in short comparing Salesforce field data with API response data)

Comment: Does the API return more than 1 row then. Maybe your split logic has to be different in production, order numbers separated by same identifier? Are you sure you have more than 1 record in SF that should match. Honestly I'd do it other way around, API call first, collect the order numbers received into `Set<String>` and then query only `WHERE Status__c = 'Paid' AND Number__c IN :paymentNumbers`. Use debug log and inspect what API returned, compare the numbers. Hard to help you without sample (even obfuscated) data

Comment: Api returns total of 600 rows but when compared it with salesforce payment object it should show 17 such records with status paid. I have tested it out for 10 rows in API and for that its working but for more rows it doesn't work. request.setTimeout(5000). I think its because of this setTimeout of 5sec

Comment: No, timeout wouldn't matter. If it'd timeout you'd get an error and you didn't post any try-catch... nothing would be sent. Set max timeout if you want (120000) but I doubt it's that.

Comment: I think the nested for loop is causing problems. When I debug paymentNo inside of if(s == oNumber), it is showing me a lots of payment numbers. And I think due to that very large number of records in comparison it is causing just 1 record to show.

Answer (score 0):

It's done. Code is fine. I was getting data from 1st page of api only thats why I was not getting all rows.